# How to replace any text between html tags

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace, grep

i have text between html tags. For example:

```
<td>vip</td>
```

I will have any text between tags `<td></td>`
How can i cut any text from these tags and put any text between these tags.
I need to do it via bash/shell.
How can i do this ?
First of all, i tried to get this text, but without success
`sed -n "/<td>/,/<\/td>/p" test.txt`. But in a result i have
`<td>vip</td>`. but according to documentation, i should get only `vip`

Comment: first of all, i tried to get this text, but without success
`sed -n "/<td>/,/<\/td>/p" test.txt`. in a result i have
`<td>vip</td>`. but according to documentation, i should get only `vip`

Comment: You should use a html parser, not regex.

Comment: Your sed attempt fails because it is a line tool, and thus prints the whole line that satisfies your criteria.

Comment: First, can you guarantee that the `<td>` and `</td>` tags are on the same line?

Comment: show more context, there should be parent `<table>` tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(<td>\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td>TEXT_TO_REPLACE_BY<\/td>/g' test.txt
```

Note that it will only work for the `<td>` tags. It will replace everything between tags `<td>` (actually with them together and put the tags back) with `TEXT_TO_REPLACE_BY`.

Comment: How would you alter this if the <td> tags were not on the same line?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get the value `vip`

```
sed -e 's,.*<td>\([^<]*\)</td>.*,\1,g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Input_file is same as shown example then following may help you too.

```
echo "<td>vip</td>" | awk -F"[><]" '{print $3}'
```

Simply printing the  tag with echo then using awk to create a field separator >< then printing the 3rd field then which is your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
d=$'<td>vip</td>\n<table>vip</table>\n<td>more data here</td>'
echo "$d"
<td>vip</td>
<table>vip</table>
<td>more data here</td> 

awk '/<td>/{match($0,/(<.*>)(.*)(<\/.*>)/,t);print t[1] "something" t[3];next}1' <<<"$d"
<td>something</td>
<table>vip</table>
<td>something</td>

awk '/<table>/{match($0,/(<.*>)(.*)(<\/.*>)/,t);print t[1] "something" t[3];next}1' <<<"$d"
<td>vip</td>
<table>something</table>
<td>more data here</td>
```