# Search and replace with sed does not work with html tags

Tags: bash, shell, search, sed, replace

i have two questions:

1) I try to replace one couple  of html tags and value between them:
i try to replace this `<td>gmail</td>` on this `<td>skype</td>`

When i tried to do this:
`sed -i -e "s/<td>gmail</td>/<td>skype</td>/g" test.txt`

,i received error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to`s'`

I understand, that i should use string, ok, let's do use this pattern:

`sed -i -e "s/'"<td>gmail</td>"'/"'<td>skype</td>'"/g" test3.txt`

in this case, i have other error:

`-su: td: No such file or directory`

Where i have error, Please help.

2) I want to make replace only on special line. For example, i have:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>gmail</td>
    <td>message-type</td>
</tr>
```

I want to replace only third line. How can i do it ?

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Learn about quoting (using `""` and `''`) and escaping.(using `\ `) special character (e.g. `/`). To do that, find an sed tutorial and work through it. Before learning sed (which is my favorite fun kind of brain-torture) consider learning perl or awk. Before doing that .. see comment by @Cyrus.

Comment: `sed -i -e "s@<td>gmail</td>@<td>skype</td>@g" test.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the line number 3 with another delimiter like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182719/3220113 (so you do not need backslashes):

```
sed -i -e '3 s#<td>gmail</td>#<td>skype</td>#g' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) Slash is a special character for sed s command. So, this is how your command is interpreted:

```
s/<td>gmail</td>/<td>skype</td>/g
  ^        ^ ^ ^ ^
  |        | | | +- options start here
  |        | | +- replacement string stops here
  |        | +- replacement string starts here
  |        +- search pattern stops here 
  +- search pattern starts here
```

If you want it to behave as a normal character, quote it with backslash. As given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369398/how-to-replace-any-text-between-html-tags).

Ad 2) `sed -e '3 s/..../'`.

PS. `man sed` is your friend.

Comment: `sed -e '3 s/.../'` is wrong , since this will replace third line of file not third `td`.

Comment: Let me quote the original question: _I want to replace only **third line**._